# What are the commands to use an openssl connection to pop3?

Tags: pop3

It is possible to get access to a text version of the email, by typing in the terminal:

*openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995 -quiet*

However the command list seems quite limited: *USER, LIST, QUIT, RETR, TOP*.

Is there a list of commands that makes it similar to mutt or other text email client?

Comment: `RETR` is exactly doing what you want: retrieve the email. If you want to send emails you need to do `SMTP` which has its own port and set of commands. But neither of them two approaches will give you an alternative to mutt.

Comment: RETR opens one email. How do you open the last message received?

Comment: By giving its number to RETR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tested the common POP commands (see list below) and all of them are working. So what specific command do you miss? Nevertheless from google's perspective this approach is considered as a security weakness, because you have to lower the protection level in gmail settings.

```
USER <username>
PASS <password>
STAT
LIST
RETR
DELE
RSET
TOP
QUIT
```